# Facebook Graph API - finding people by filters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a facebook application which would allow to search for people by numerous filters such as sex, age, country. I skimmed through facebook graph api and found that it was ... impossible. In other words, there is no way to find people by  sex, age or country using facebook api.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: It’s not the intention behind Facebook to be a stalker’s tool to find prey by such criteria ;-)

Comment: Oh they're such good guys.